# How pass data from child to parent: Angular Color Picker [(colorPicker)]

Tags: javascript, angular

https://github.com/Alberplz/angular2-color-picker

I've create a child component where I am loading the angular 2 color picker

In my child component HTML I've have

```
  <span [(colorPicker)]="arrayColors[selectedColor]"     
    [cpDialogDisplay]="'inline'"
    [style.background]="colors[selectedColor]"
    [cpToggle]="true">
</span>
```

How can I pass `arrayColors[selectedColor]`  data to parent component, if is not a function and I can not emit an event listener because it is not a func?

Comment: really Maxim ? Great job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
 <span [(colorPicker)]="arrayColors[selectedColor]" (colorPickerChange)="func($event)"
```

to call a function in addition to updating `arrayColors[selectedColor]`

Comment: Wow, that simple. Thank you Gunter!
So I can add "Change" to any of the attributes and angular will understand? Do you have a reference to this where you read about it, to see what else I can find?

Comment: `[(colorPicker)]="foo"` is the short form of `[colorPicker]="foo" (colorPickerChange)="foo = $event"`. This means `[(colorPicker)]="foo"` is only valid if there is an input `colorPicker` and an output `colorPickerChange`. It is mentioned briefly in the template syntax docs (only on my phone just now, therefore no link)